# Multiple IFs in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write the following SQL query where I have to select different functions for different inputs. The functions returns the number of employees in each department after checking the @Dept parameter.

```
DECLARE @Dept varchar(10)='IT'

IF @Dept='IT'
    Select count(Employees) from dbo.ITDept()
IF @Dept='HR'
    Select count(Employees) from dbo.HRDept()
IF @Dept='Accounts'
    Select count(Employees) from dbo.AccountsDept()
```

Is there a better way of writing this query?

Comment: Yes, user CASE instead of IF (since in your example there are three evaluations regardless of the value of `@Dept`).

Comment: Do you have access to the base table of these table functions?

Comment: No. I can only use the functions to access the tables.

Answer (score 1):

I think you try to use it like a field in a query. You can handle it with this

```
Declare @dept varchar(10)
SELECT  CASE WHEN @dept='IT' THEN 
(Select 
count(Employees) from dbo.ITDept()) 
WHEN @dept='IT' THEN (Select count(Employees) from dbo.HRDept()) 
WHEN @dept='IT' THEN (Select count(Employees) from dbo.AccountsDept())  
ELSE (Select count(Employees) from dbo.ITDept())  
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Without an access to the base objects of the table functions, the answer is 'No'.
It can be written in a single query, but it has no added value.